# AngularJS UI-Router 0.X issues getting an if statement to trigger on initial app load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

JS:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$http', '$state', 'segment',
function run($rootScope, $http, $state, segment) {

  let publicStates = [
    'register',
    'forgotPassword',
    'passwordreset',
    'login',
  ];

  // Add JWT token as default auth header.
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' +
  window.localStorage.getItem('userToken');

  // Check that user is logged in.
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {

    $rootScope.$state = toState;

    if (!window.localStorage.getItem('userToken') &&
        publicStates.indexOf(toState.name) === -1) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('login');
    }

    if (publicStates.indexOf(toState.name) === -1) {
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#gs')).css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#gs')).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
    segment.page(toState.name, {
      path: toState.name,
      referrer: fromState.url,
      url: toState.url,
    });
  });
}]);
```

Referring to the last if/else statement:

All this does is hide/show an element if the current route name isn't in an array.  It works great, but it doesn't run on initial app load.  Examples:

- Open App on the page where the element should be hidden, but it is shown.
- Refresh on the same page, and the element is still shown.
- Navigate to a different page, and it works perfectly.

How can I get this particular if/else statement to run every time without error, even on page refresh?

Sidenote:  I have to do it dynamically this way because the element in question is being dynamically inserted via a JS dependency.

Comment: did you console log or breakpoint to see if this was running on page reload? Is this in a run block or config block or neither?

Comment: Have you tried using `$stateChangeSuccess` for that 2nd if statement?  The DOM elements shouldn't even exist when `$stateChangeStart` fires so the fact that it works when navigating is a bit surprising.

Comment: Also where is this code contained?  If the watcher isn't defined before the `$stateChangeStart` fires on reload it obviously won't catch the event.

Comment: If you want to avoid a state from being visible, return a rejected promise to a resolve function to abort loading of the state's template.

Comment: The use of `document.querySelector` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of large problem.

Comment: @BShaps it's in app.run

Comment: @BShaps yeah I've tried it in `$stateChangeSuccess` as well as `$viewContentLoaded`

Comment: @JoeBerthelot Before or after the `$stateProvider.states` and `publicStates` are defined?  I have never tried anything like this so I'm not sure, but I would imagine that you need it after publicStates is defined, but before the states are defined.

Comment: @BShaps it's after.  I've updated the original post with the full app.run function.  Thank you for your time on this,